# Rock, Paper Scissors game in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

I wrote a simple Rock, Paper Scissors game in Python for class. As a beginner, I would like some input as to how I could abstract or make my code smoother. I feel like the repeated use of `if` or `elif` statements are overbearing. I would like any tips or advice, or perhaps a different method of approach.

```
import random
user = ''

while user != 'q':
    print('Enter your choice')
    print('R or r for rock\nP or p for paper\nS or s for scissors\nQ or q to quit')
    user = input('')
    user = user.lower()
    if user == 'q':
        break
    comp = random.randrange(1, 4)
    choice = comp

    # assign (int) to user choices
    if user == 'r':
        user = 1
    elif user == 'p':
        user = 2
    elif user == 's':
        user = 3

    # assign string to computer random choice
    if   comp == 1:
        choice = 'rock'
    elif comp == 2:
        choice = 'paper'
    elif comp == 3:
        choice = 'scissors'

    print('Computer picked:', choice)

    # compare selection to figure out the winner
    if user == 1 and comp == 3:
        print('You win against the computer\n')
    elif user == 3 and comp == 1:
        print('You lose against the computer\n')
    elif user > comp:
        print('You win against the computer\n')
    elif user < comp:
        print('You lose against the computer\n')
    elif user == comp:
        print('You tie against the computer\n')
```

Comment: What about 'switch case'?

Comment: @thescion: As this is Python, there is no switch case. That said, RPS is trivially coded up with a dictionary.

Comment: Other comments aside, you should not call that variable 'user'. 'user_input' or 'user_choice' might be better. Names matter because they help you get an understanding of what your code is doing and how to structure it.

Comment: We have a [tag:rock-paper-sciccors] tag. Feel free to browse those questions for alternative implementations. There should be a couple in [tag:python] as well.

Comment: Your title should indicate what the code is intended to do - please read our [ask], because it's quite different to that of [so].

Comment: I don't think scissors made of paper would be very effective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are trying to solve this problem does not seem pythonic. Since `switch` statements don't exist in python, you can simulate `switch`-like behaviour using dictionaries.

For example, instead of using `if`-`else` to set the value of `user`, you can so something like

```
user_options = {
    'r': 1,
    'p': 2,
    's': 3
}
user = user_options[user]
```

Since functions and classes are first-class objects in python, if you want to accomplish some less trivial, you can use them too:

```
def func1():
    # do some operation

def func2():
    # some other operation

def default_func():
    # some default action

options = {
    '1': func1,
    '2': func2,
    'default': default_func
}

value = raw_input('enter a number')

result = options.get(int(value), options.get('default'))()
```

If your functions are simple enough, you can use lambdas as values, which would definitely be more concise.

Comment: What is `user = user_options[user]` doing? You define the dictionary first and then set `user` equal to the corresponding value in the dictionary?

Comment: In your code, you are setting user =1 if it is equal to 'r', that's exactly what that statement is doing

Comment: Your code won't work. `options[int('1')]` won't lookup on `'1'`.

Comment: You are right. One has to convert into an integer first. Anyway I was just giving him only a general idea on how to approach toward solution.

Answer (score 12):

In Python you can compare multiple values the following way:

```
if (user, comp) in {(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)} :
    print('You win against the computer\n')
elif user == comp :
    print('You tie against the computer\n')
else :
    print('You lose against the computer\n')
```

Comment: Why do you have curly braces instead of square brackets around the list of win-conditions? That makes it a `dict` without values but only keys?

Comment: @MartinUeding That's a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: Cool, I did not know that. Seems to be added in Python 3.1, so it is safe to use on all my targeted platforms. Lookup in the set will be faster, so that is a neater solution; though it won't matter with three elements.

Comment: That makes a `Set`. Technically it is indeed a dictionary with only keys. This structure from Python 2, since Python 2.7, `{}` can be used to declare a set

Answer (score 10):

Here are 3 corrections. Instead of manually converting `r,s,p` and `1,2,3`, use a dictionary. Instead of using a random number for the computers choice, use the players options. Instead of having extra `win/lose/tie` checks, have one per outcome.

#### Fix Conversion

This is a simple way to convert `r,p,s` into a name or a value:

- `options['r']['name'] == 'Rock'`
- `options['r']['value'] == 1`

```
options = {
    'r':{'name':'Rock','value':1},
    'p':{'name':'Paper','value':2},
    's':{'name':'Scissors','value':3}
}
```

#### Fix Computer's Choice

By choosing a random key from options prevents having to hard-code values. It also allows us to lookup the name and value for the computer's choice. `compChoice` will be `r, p, or s` since those are options' keys.

```
compChoice = random.choice(list(options.keys()))
```

#### Fix `win/lose/tie` Checks

A tie only happens if `compValue==userValue`. Now consider **+1 mod 3**, for any value if you *"+1 mod 3"* you will get the only value that can beat it:

- `rocVal+1 %3 == papVal`
- `papVal+1 %3 == sciVal`
- `sciVal+1 %3 == rocVal`

```
compVal = options[compChoice]['value']
userVal = options[userChoice]['value']
result = 'win'

if userVal == compVal: result = 'tie'
elif userVal+1 % 3 == compVal: result = 'lose'
# else: result = 'win'

print('You '+result+' against the computer!\n')
```

---

**Advanced Check**

But what if you want to play Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock? Or a any version with more than 3 options? If that is the case, here is a scalable solution from [sch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9553712/4769802). Note that the number of options should always be odd. This way each element has the same number of superiors and inferiors.

**Explanation:** the key piece here is the *decider*. Picture these options as being on a circle (e.g. an analog clock). *decider* is the clockwise distance from `b` to `a`. [Note: if this distance is even, then the distance from `a` to `b` is odd] For any particular option, half of the remaining options are an even distance and half are an odd distance. Here we arbitrary choose that odd distances correspond to a loss.

```
compVal = options[compChoice]['value']
userVal = options[userChoice]['value']
numOpns = len(options)
decider = (userVal-compVal) % numOpns
result = 'win'

if decider == 0: result = 'tie'
elif decider%2 == 0: result = 'lose'
# else decider%2 == 1: result = 'win'

print('You '+result+' against the computer!\n')
```

In this case, **hints** are definitely a problem if hard coded. So here is a fix for that:

```
for k,v in options.iteritems():
    print(k.upper()+" or "+k+" for "+v['name'])
print('Q or q to quit')
```

And while we are at it, here is an options dictionary that simulates the correct Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock [relationship](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Rock_Paper_Scissors_Lizard_Spock_en.svg/2000px-Rock_Paper_Scissors_Lizard_Spock_en.svg.png).

```
options = {
    'r':{'name':'Rock','value':5},
    'l':{'name':'Lizard','value':4},
    'o':{'name':'Spock','value':3},
    's':{'name':'Scissors','value':2},
    'p':{'name':'Paper','value':1}
}
```

Comment: You could probably replace your "magic" 3 with `len(options)`.

Comment: @Dubu The magic number works for 1 option and 3 options but fails for 5 and larger. Changing to `len(options)` won't improve this (and it will make it less readable). But abstracting away the 3 is a good idea. I added an 'advanced check' section which contains a generic solution for any odd number of options.

Comment: Is `'r':{'name':'Rock','value':1}` a dictionary, within a dictionary? 
`options = { }` is the "parent" dictionary?

Comment: @RichardPeña Yes, it is a dictionary in a dictionary with `options` being the parent. It makes the code a little more readable.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit I am rewriting my code and am getting an error with a call similar to `compChoice = random.choice(options.keys())` I should be able to yield the same results with 
`comp_choice = {1: 'rock', 2: 'paper', 3: 'scissors'}                               comp_play = random.choice(comp_choice.keys())`

Comment: @RichardPeña Thanks for catching that. In Python 3, we need to make the keys into a list: `random.choice(list(options.keys()))`.

Comment: `numOpns` ... `% numOpns` seems a little redundant. It's like adding 0.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You are correct! In Java, the mod op's codomain is `(-n,n)` (i.e.  `-8%5==-3`). I assumed this was the case in Python, but it is not.

Answer (score 3):

My second pass,

Improvements:

1. Use list and string to find the user's and computer's move easily, instead of doing if-elses.
2. Never trust user input. Verify that the user input is one of r, p, s or q.

   ```
   import random

   user = ''
   while user != 'q':
       print('Enter your choice')
       print('R or r for rock\nP or p for paper\nS or s for scissors\nQ or q to quit')
       user = input('')
       user = user.lower()
       choices = 'rps'

       if user == 'q':
           break
       if user not in choices:
           print 'invalid choice'
           continue
       user = choices.find(user)

       comp = random.randrange(0, 3)
       choice = comp

       choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
       print('Computer picked:', move_choices[comp])

       # compare selection to figure out the winner
       if user == 0 and comp == 2:
           print('You win against the computer\n')
       elif user == 2 and comp == 0:
           print('You lose against the computer\n')
       elif user > comp:
           print('You win against the computer\n')
       elif user < comp:
           print('You lose against the computer\n')
       elif user == comp:
           print('You tie against the computer\n')
   ```

Comment: 'if choices.find(user) == -1': I find it more readable to write 'if user not in choices'

Comment: agreed and updated :)

Comment: Your indentation seems to have become corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the if/elif improvements, you can also to some other things (here I take tips from all the answers to give you a good solution):

```
import random

print('Tip:\nR or r for rock\nP or p for paper\nS or s for scissors\nQ or q to quit')
while True:
    user = input('Enter you choice\n> ').lower()
    options = {'r': 1, 'p': 2, 's': 3}
    comp_trans = {1: 'rock', 2: 'paper', 3: 'scissors'}
    if user == 'q':
        break
    elif user not in options.keys():
        print('Invalid input, please re try')
        continue
    comp_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
    user_choice = options[user]
    print('Computer choosed:', comp_trans[comp_choice])
    if (user_choice, comp_choice) in {(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)}:
        print('You won!')
    elif user_choice == comp_choice:
        print('You tied!')
    else:
        print('You lost!')
```

Changes:

1) Instead of giving tips every game, we give it once.

2) We dont need to check if user == 'q' each loop (in while statement) because you already do it in the loop

3) if you need only once a value, instead of creating a variable for it and using the variable directly use the value (in displaying the computer choose)

4) we need to check the input, or we may get a KeyError on the line

```
user_choice = options[user]
```

5) you asked what does the previous line do: it defines the variable *user_choice* to the value *options[user]*. *options[user]* returns the value in the dictionary *options* that has the key *user*. For example, if *user = 'r'*, *options[user]* will return *1*.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, your first answer looks good, enjoy your stay!

Comment: How does `if (user_choice, comp_choice) in {(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)}:` work?
If user is: 1 while comp is 3, 2 while comp is 1, 3 while comp is 2?

Comment: @RichardPeña In that case, the other option (`else`) will be chosen, because the other person wins.

Comment: @RichardPeña you create an object of type tuple (user_choice, comp_choice), and check if there is the same in a set that contains 3 tuples. The difference between set and tuples is that each object in set is unique, and set is not ordered. This increases efficiencity.

Answer (score 1):

Python has native lists, tuples and dictionaries (and a number of other data-structures).  If you use the builtin data structures wisely you can often drastically simplify your code.  In your case you are mapping back and forth between ints (1,2,3), characters ('r', 'p' and 's') and names ('rock',.. etc).    Having the ints isn't necessary and the mapping from chars to names is better done with a dict.

```
import random

options = {"r": "rock", "p": "paper", "s": "scissors"}

while True:
    user = input('Choose r for rock, p for paper, s for scissors or q to quit: ')
    user = user.lower()

    if user == 'q':
        break

    if user not in options.keys():
        continue

    choice = random.choice(list(options.keys()))
    print('Computer picked:', options[choice])

    if choice == user:
        print('You tie against the computer\n')
    elif (user, choice) in (("r", "s"), ("p", "r"), ("s", "p")):
        print('You win against the computer\n')
    else:
        print('You lose against the computer\n')
```